# scroll not work when the hold on input native base

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scroll, scrollview

Iam beginner in react native. In my project iam using native base component and in content area using the icon and input, when screen load i can not hold scroll on input how can I fix this bug. Thanks for your help

my code:

```
<Container style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
  <Content>   
    <Label style={registerstyle.LableS}>گذرواژه</Label>
    <Input />

  </Content>
 </Container>
```

example gif:
[image]